# Amenable link groups

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, knot-theory, 3-manifolds, knot-link

The unknot and the Hopf link are (as far as I know) the only links whose complements have abelian fundamental groups. Are there more examples whose complement have amenable fundamental group?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.  Suppose that $K$ is a non-trivial knot.  Then its knot genus is at least one.  Thus $X = S^3 - K$ contains a $\pi_1$-essential surface (with boundary) of genus at least one.  Thus $\pi_1(X)$ contains a free group of rank at least two.

The story for links is similar.

---

A more subtle proof uses the geometrisation theorem.  Every link is either a split link, a torus link, a satellite link, or a hyperbolic link.  Torus link complements (other than of the unknot and Hopf link) fibre over a base orbifold with negative Euler characteristic - this gives the desired free group.  Hyperbolic knot complements have free groups in their fundamental groups for geometric reasons. Split (satellite) links have an essential sphere (torus) in their complement - so cut and induct.

Comment: The claim "Every link is either a torus link, a satellite link, or a hyperbolic link." is wrong (true for knots).

Comment: Good point. I’ve added the missing case.